# C++ inherit template specializations

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function that does something depending on the type passed as a template argument:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo() {
  if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
    //  ...
  } else if constexpr ... {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The problem with this it that I don't really need to have a function instantiation for every possible integral type (to avoid template code bloat), so I would like to have only one instance that takes a `int` and if we pass the type `char` or `short` it calls the `int` version. I would like something like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) { // Only check for `int`, because "lower" types will be converted to int
    //  ...
  } else if constexpr ... {
    // ...
  }
}

foo<short>(); // Call `foo<int>`
foo<char>(); // Call `foo<int>`
foo<int>(); // Call `foo<int>`
```

Maybe I can wrap the function inside a struct and have a `struct<char>` that extends the `struct<int>`?

Note that there is no "values" anywhere, I just have template parameters.

Comment: Ok, so? What is your question? Did you try what you proposed? What happened?

Comment: You could make a `jojolatino::is_sameish_v<T, int>` with the conditional behavior you want.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::is_convertible_v<T, int>` ?

Comment: @Eljay But this would require to instantiate a `foo<T>` for every possble T

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't try to use a `struct<char>` that inherits the `struct<int>`, I think it could work, what do you think? I'm just exposing my problem and a solution that I have thought of, but I don't know if I'm missing a better solution

Comment: As far as I know you can not avoid the template instantiations because of the internal working of templates which requires the compiler to instantiate every specialization if it doedn’t already exist.

Comment: *"to avoid template code bloat"* Do you really encounter a issue? If block inside the `if` is really duplicated inside each instantiation, is moving that code inside `foo_int` and call that one resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn `foo` into a callable object, and use `using` alias to select different instantiations according to `T`, for example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct foo {
 void operator()() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
      //  ...
    } else if constexpr ... {
      // ...
    }
 }
};

template<class T>
auto bar = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, foo<int>, foo<T>>();

int main() {
  bar<short>(); // Call `foo<int>`
  bar<char>();  // Call `foo<int>`
  bar<int>();   // Call `foo<int>`
  bar<const char*>(); // Call `foo<const char*>`
}
```